# software-update returning "No new software available."

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, software-update

Under **MacOS Sierra 10.12.5**, I wrote the following script  that I put in `/usr/local/bin/update` to update all my packages at once:

```
#!/bin/sh
brew update
brew upgrade
brew cask outdated|xargs brew cask reinstall
softwareupdate -ia
```

It always worked like a charm, including when installing *MacOS* system updates. But this time, I have an app (*Slack*) which is marked by the *App Store* as  updatable (to the version *2.6.2* whereas mine is *2.6.0*) but `softwareupdate -ia` returns

```
Software Update Tool  
Finding available software  
No new software available.
```

Even when running `softwareupdate --clear-catalog --force --reset-ignored --list`, no available update whereas it's showing in the *App Store*.

Here is an unresolved thread with someone who had the problem too: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2396385

Any idea? Has anyone met the same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post gave me a doubt: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110312/cli-softwareupdate-does-not-find-updates.

Especially:

> The CLI tool softwareupdate is only for OS X updates provided through Apple's
>   software update catalog, or whichever .sucatalog is set in preferences for
>   catalogs provided by OS X Server's Software Update service.
>
> This update catalog does not contain details for Mac App Store apps, such as Xcode.

So I installed [**mas**](https://github.com/mas-cli/mas) (Mac App Store command line interface), which allows to update the apps by running `mas upgrade`, and added this command in my script.